# Save multiple command results to txt file

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have given a bat file that I should run on development server which does some updates.

It has multiple commands and I would like to keep the results in txt file.

Should I add after each command >> result.txt or I can add it somewhere in the end of bat file and everything will be written in that?

Answer (score 4):

You have four options:

- Run the batch file at the command line like:  myBat.bat >> outPut.txt
- Script the above in another batch file and run that
- Insert the >> after **each** command ( Note: the >> appends to file, while > overrides existing text output file)
- Enclose all relevant lines in parentheses and script >> result.txt **once** at the end of the script

Comment: 4.) enclose all relevant lines in parantheses  and do `>>result.txt` only once.

Comment: ^ Also that! I won't add to my answer so you can get any up votes.. probably many many more options as well

Comment: feel free to use it for your answer. Three solutions from you, one from me. It's you who deserves the upvotes ;)

Comment: Alternatively, instead of `>>`, find a windows version of the unix `tee` utility to both see the output *and* redirect it to capture results.

Comment: @PA Good tip but I think the OP is talking about windows only??

Comment: yes! that's why I suggested *find a **windows version** of*